# How to solve $z^3=\frac12-\frac12i$

Tags: complex-numbers

After simplifying the equation:

$(2i)^9z^3=(1+i)^{17}$

I got at the end that: $z^3=\frac12-\frac12i$

but I didn't know how to take it from here, and how to find $z_1$, $z_2$, $z_3$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** write $$
(1-i) = \sqrt 2 e^{-i\pi / 4} = \sqrt 2(\cos(-\pi / 4) + i \sin(-\pi / 4))
$$

Comment: I didn't learn this form of solving, can I do it according to other easy way, or using De Moivre formula?

Comment: It will be equivalent, you will have to go back to this formula. Look at my edit, you can identify with the De Moivre formula now.

Comment: you're right. I realized my mistake now. thanks !

Comment: ofc, i can accept it only in 6 mins ;)